# Oracle Uknown Command Error when executing stored proc

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am using SQl Developer to execute a procedure with in a package named CONTRACTOR_REG. The procedure has the following signiture.

```
PROCEDURE usp_ins_contractor_all(
          webid          VARCHAR2,--
          firstname      VARCHAR2,--
          lastname       VARCHAR2,--
          middlename     VARCHAR2,--
          busname        VARCHAR2,--
          townname       VARCHAR2,--
          strname        VARCHAR2,--
          strtypecd      VARCHAR2,--
          strpfxcd       VARCHAR2,--
          strsfxcd       VARCHAR2,--
          addressoverflo VARCHAR2,--
          houseno        VARCHAR2,--
          zipcd          VARCHAR2,--
          state          VARCHAR2,--
          phonenum       VARCHAR2,--
          phonenight     VARCHAR2,
          phonecell      VARCHAR2,--
          phonefax       VARCHAR2,--
          phonepager     VARCHAR2,
          licno          VARCHAR2,--
          regSite        VARCHAR2,
          licstate       VARCHAR2,--
          level_type     VARCHAR2 := 'NA',--
          type_cd        CHAR)
```

I am trying to execute the following:

```
exec user1.contractor_reg.usp_ins_contractor_all('testing12345',
          'test',
          'me',
          'a',
          'testbiz',
          'DFGGH',
          'something',
          null,
          null,
          null,
          'pobox:12345',
          '45',
          '00000',
          'DF',
          '1231231231',
          '2342342344',
          '443243242',
          '111111111',
          null,
          '123123123',
          null,
          'FD',
          'NA',
          'EC')
```

I get following error:

```
Error starting at line 25 in command:
          'EC')
Error report:
Unknown Command
```

Seems really random to me, whats wrong with my last parameter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it really a stored procedure, or is it a procedure within a package?

Comment: procedure within a package, aorry guess i should have been more clear, i'm used to mssql.

Answer (score 4):

The reason mentioned in your reply might not be the reason for the error.

As Alex mentioned below, to use EXEC with SQLPLUS, you need use the continuation character, if your command spans multiple lines...

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12022.htm#i2697931

EXEC is a SQLPLUS command. when you use..

```
exec p1;
```

in sqlplus,it in turn adds a begin and end block to execute your procedure...

```
begin
  p1;
end;
/
```

Not sure if SQL Developer supports this.I don't have access to SQL Developer at work, but..

Have you tried executing this procedure using BEGIN-END ?

```
begin
  user1.contractor_reg.usp_ins_contractor_all('testing12345',
          'test',
          'me',
          'a',
          'testbiz',
          'DFGGH',
          'something',
          null,
          null,
          null,
          'pobox:12345',
          '45',
          '00000',
          'DF',
          '1231231231',
          '2342342344',
          '443243242',
          '111111111',
          null,
          '123123123',
          null,
          'FD',
          'NA',
          'EC');
end;
/
```

Comment: I found that BEGIN/END is required when I developed an SP wrapper using NHibernate

Comment: yes this also works, just need to add in a `;` after the stored proc call

Comment: The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12022.htm#i2697931) for `EXEC` mentions that the command has to fit on one line, but can be explicitly continued.

Comment: @Alex -- you are right. I totally forgot that exec works differently with line breaks. Probably the result of working with Toad/other tools, I though Line breaks work perfectly fine with all tools. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Rajesh: using an anonymous block still tends to be more readable with more than a couple of arguments, so it's useful to point out what's happening under the hood. And when copying a chunk of code it's easier to slap a begin/end around it than add a load of hyphens...

Comment: @Alex - Totally agree... Most of the one-time insert/change scripts that I want to run have the same format as above.. Begin.. <package/procedure_Call> end; /

Answer (score 1):

Aparently, you cannot have line breaks inbetween each paramter like I did... Stupid program...

exec user1.contractor_reg.usp_ins_contractor_all('testing12345','test','me','a','testbiz','sdfsdf','something',null,null,null,'pobox:12345','45','00000','sdfff', '1231231231', '2342342344', '443243242', '111111111', null, '123123123', null, 'sdff', 'E1','EC')

Comment: Plain line breaks don't work in `EXEC` in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer. You can, though, use the continuation character (`-`) to continue the command on to a second line; at least in SQL*Plus, haven't tested in SQL Developer. [Documentation for SQL*Plus](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12022.htm#i2697931)

Comment: @alex, is there actually a good reason for this? Why can't it just egnore the whitespace like everyother language...

Comment: it's not really a language issue, it's how the client (SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, at least) is interpreting and transforming the call you present to be `EXEC`'d. If you tried to type the whole call in to SQL*Plus it would try to execute it as soon as you hit return the first time, it doesn't wait for (or need) the trailing `;`. I suspect SQL Developer copies it for compatibility. No idea if there's a reason though, may be historic, based on how the client is or was constrained. You'd need to ask Oracle *8-)

Comment: @alex - i understand that it's just the way that sql developer interperats the code, however there just seem to be a lot of things about sql developer that suck compared to say... SSMS. Everyone always says Oracle is more powerful than MSsql server, and that may be true(although I have not needed to do something Oracle could do that sql could not), but SSMS is a shit load easier to use than Sql Developer.